# Visual Studio Code - Add Reference Errors

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-code

When I open *Visual Studio 2013 C# project* in ***Visual Studio Code (v 0.1.0)*** editor, download link [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/), I'm getting dozen of errors:

> The type 'Object' is defined in the assembly that is not referenced.
>   You must add reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.
>   [my c# project name]

Project uses *.NET Framework 4.5*. *mscorelib.dll* automatically referenced when project is opened in Visual Studio 2013 is *Version=4.0.0.0*.

Is there a way to configure VS2013 project, so that *Visual Studio Code* recognizes references and Framework version properly?

*System: Windows, no Visual Studio 2015 components installed.*

Comment: How are you opening a VS 2013 C# project in Visual Studio Code?  The options I see are to open a file (*File* > *Open File...*) or open a folder (*File* > *Open Folder...*).  If I open the folder for a VS 2013 C# project that targets .NET Framework 4.5, I do not get any errors, just its files listed in the *EXPLORE* panel.  If I open its `.csproj` file, Code just opens it to edit like any XML file.

Comment: I use `File > Open Folder`. But, interestingly, with new MVC WebApplication project  I'm getting only warnings for assembly version miss-match 'Assuming assembly reference '....', you man need to supply runtime policy [WebApplcation1]'. I could not find any significant difference between csproj and web.config in my project and in new MVC app.

Answer (score 1):

According this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30916540/1698964) you can try the following to solve your issue:

> I was able to fix this by issuing an `update-package -reinstall` command at the Package Manager Console.