# MSBuild conflict between mscorlib 4.x and mscorlib 2.x

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, mscorlib

I was investigating a build failure recently and saw a warning about conflicts between assemblies. I dug deeper and MSBuild told me this:

> There was a conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes".
>         "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" was chosen because it was primary and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes" was not.`

My solution contains several console applications, lots of class libraries and ASP.NET application. We build on .NET 4.5.2.

Should I be concerned?

Comment: No, that's a normal warning when you a reference on a PCL assembly.  You only ever see it when you "dig deeper".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mscorlib version conflict during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881648/mscorlib-version-conflict-during-build)

Answer (score 2):

When using PCL libraries it is better add `Microsoft.Bcl.Build` Nuget package which will attempt to resolve this issue for your.
Also you should investigate dependencies of your class libraries and find where you depends on the PCL library.

Comment: I do this on Visual Studio Mac, However, the build process still gives the same error