# There was a conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

While playing with ASP.Net Core I tried to bring-in a custom code-library of my own and got these messages:

> No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib,
> Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e,
> Retargetable=Yes". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
>
> No way to resolve conflict between "System, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System,
> Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e,
> Retargetable=Yes". Choosing "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.

**Q:** Is it possible to make the 2 versions "play well" together?
**Q:** Is it a good idea to even try?

**NOTES:**
running `update-package -reinstall` uninstalled all references to Entity Framework, Unity and so on...so this isn't the "fix".

Comment: The duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881648/mscorlib-version-conflict-during-build