# Deploy failed on Android with Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

When I only build application its fine, without errors but on deploy there is fail. I tried on empty project with the same result. I tried with other phone and onther computer, but it still fail. I am using jdk1.8.0_161

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi5Gl.jpg

Comment: Hi, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881648/mscorlib-version-conflict-during-build).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled all JDKs form computer, restared nad installed new JDK, that helped. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reconnect your device:

- Open the **Android Adb Command Prompt** (next to Android SDK Manager icon)
- Type in **adb connect 127.0.0.1:5554** (with 5554 being the port of your device)