# c# net can't publish project, build succeeded in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

i read similar/ same questions before. but no solution worked for me.

i tried to deploy the webservice to a destination folder and it fails after build succeeded. the error message and problem is the same like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103014/project-builds-but-cant-publish)

```
       3>------ Publish started: Project: Webservice_ex, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
3>Connecting to D:\Deploys...
3>Project "Webservice_ex.csproj" (GatherAllFilesToPublish target(s)):
3>    Building with tools version "14.0".
3>    Target "ValidateMSBuildToolsVersion" skipped. Previously built unsuccessfully.
3>Done building project "Webservice_ex.csproj" -- FAILED.
3>
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

the difference between the other questions is, that i can't fix the problem with downgrading Microsoft.Net.Compilers, because i don't have the package installed. i have two projects within one sln while on is only a referenced project.

can somebody help me?

UPDATE

the detailed output says this (extract):

```
1>  There was a conflict between "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes".
1>      "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes" was not.
1>      References which depend on "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.
```

[...]

```
Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(OutDir)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(OutDir)')) was evaluated as ('bin\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('bin\')).
```

Comment: the language barrier is a little bit of an issue

Comment: changed the language of the error message

Comment: in your solution, are there any icons with an exclamation point that means they are not present locally

Comment: thanks for the comment. but no, i don't have any icons in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"solved" it using visual studio 2017 for publishing.

Answer (score 1):

Please enabled the detailed logging of the build out put, it will give the exact error why publish is failing.

In my case, file name was exceeding 256 characters and MSBuild does not like it.

Follow these steps to enable the detailed logging in build output

To change the amount of information included in the build log

- On the menu bar, choose Tools, Options.
- On the Projects and Solutions page
- choose the Build and Run page.
- In the MSBuild project build output verbosity list, choose Detailed and then choose the OK button

and we can continue to look for the problem like possible missing files

with your error now examined please look at possible duplicate here in stackoverflow here..

[mscorlib version conflict during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881648/mscorlib-version-conflict-during-build)

Comment: sorry that it took so long. thanks for the answer! i changed it from diagnostic to detailed and now its a little bit clearer. i updated my post with an extract of possible causes from the output.

Comment: i left a link on resolutions to your issue

Comment: unfortunately none of the solutions worked for me. maybe i should try creating a fresh vs project and install all packages new.