# Unable to start debugging vs 2017

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, mscorlib

I'm developping xamarin forms app, i seted the android project as startup project, and when i run the poject on my device i got this error

```
>    Start debugging Android application ...
>     Starting Android application ...
>     An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details.
>     Unable to start debugging.
>     The specified file can not be found.
```

1- where i can find the logs file ?

and this the output of the build

```
    Starting runtime checks
Detecting installed packages
Detecting installed packages...
1>------ Build started: Project: MobileApp2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Runtime checks completed

2>  No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
3>Starting deploy Samsung SM-J320F ...
3>Deploying Samsung SM-J320F ...
3>Build started.
3>Project "MobileApp2.Android.csproj" (Install target(s)):
3>Project "MobileApp2.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):
3>Done building project "MobileApp2.csproj".
3>Project "MobileApp2.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):
3>Done building project "MobileApp2.csproj".
3>Project "MobileApp2.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):
3>Done building project "MobileApp2.csproj".

3>Done building project "MobileApp2.Android.csproj".
3>Build succeeded.
3>Deploy successfully on Samsung SM-J320F
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

the best solution [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41586641/6014094) is to update nugat packages, i do it but the problem persists

2- first i want to understand the problem, ther's a conficlt but where ?

Comment: You can find the log in "Visual Studio -> Help -> Xamarin -> Logs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you disabled the mono debugging in tools and extension -> Mono debugging for visual studio. Enable it. Or check if you have enabled any extension visual studio suggested you. For me by disabling Xamarin.Android SDK exension, restarted the visual studio and it worked for me.